# Join 2 tables with multiple DISTINCT

Tags: php, mysql, join

i an trying to get values from table using DISTINCT but this is not working, here is wt i am doing

```
SELECT top100albums.songs, english_fm.artist, 
    english_fm.album, english_fm.image
FROM top100albums, english_fm
WHERE top100albums.songs = english_fm.album
```

i am confused how can i use DISTINCT  in this query can i use it like this ...

```
 SELECT  top100albums.songs, english_fm.DISTINCT(artist), 
     english_fm.DISTINCT(album), english_fm.DISTINCT(image)
 FROM top100albums, english_fm
 WHERE top100albums.songs = english_fm.album
```

this is wrong ...

i want to get DISTINCT (not repeated result of these rows artist,album,image from table english_fm, so how can i do that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
   SELECT top100albums.songs, english_fm.artist, english_fm.album, english_fm.image
   FROM top100albums, english_fm
   WHERE top100albums.songs = english_fm.album
   GROUP BY english_fm.artist, english_fm.album, english_fm.image
```

insetead of distinct  use group by

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT top100albums.songs, english_fm.artist, english_fm.album, english_fm.image
FROM top100albums, english_fm
WHERE top100albums.songs = english_fm.album
GROUP BY top100albums.songs, english_fm.artist, english_fm.album, english_fm.image
```

Answer (score 1):

This is fully optimized query with needed result.

Try this

```
SELECT ta.songs, ef.artist, ef.album, ef.image
FROM english_fm AS ef
INNER JOIN top100albums AS ta ON ef.album = ta.songs
GROUP BY ef.artist, ef.album, ef.image;
```

Hope, this will helpful

Answer (score 0):

`DISTINCT` keyword tells engine to return unique cortege (result set record). See usage in documentation.

[SELECT Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html)

Answer (score 0):

`DISTINCT` applies for the rows and not for individual columns.

So use `GROUP BY' for your requirement.

```
SELECT top100albums.songs, english_fm.artist, english_fm.album), english_fm.image
 FROM top100albums, english_fm
 WHERE top100albums.songs = english_fm.album GROUP BY english_fm.artist, english_fm.album, english_fm.image;
```